Find $\displaystyle\int_\Gamma \frac{\tan z}{z^2+\pi^2} \, dz$ where $\Gamma$ is the circle $\left|z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right|=1$
Find $\displaystyle\int_\Gamma \frac{\tan z}{z^2+\pi^2} \, dz$ where $\Gamma$ is the circle $\left|z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right|=1$.
This problem showed up on a qualifying exam where the usual "find the integral" problem utilizes the Residue theorem, particularly when the singularities of the integrand occur at poles. Here, the only singularity which is interior to $\Gamma$ is an essential singularity at $z = \frac{\pi}{2}$. From my understanding, the case of singularities which are essential do not retain a nice formula/procedure for calculation; rather, explicit calculation of Laurent series may be needed here. So with partial fractions,
$$\oint \frac{\tan z}{(z-\pi i)(z+\pi i)} \,dz = A \oint  \frac{\tan z}{z-\pi i} \,dz  + B \oint \frac{\tan z}{z+\pi i} \, dz$$
But the Taylor expansion of $\tan z$ utilizes the Bernoulli numbers which is a concept that is certainly beyond the intended scope of the problem (it's a qualification exam problem as I said). How might this integral be found without use of such higher-order tools?

Higher-order tools ??? !!!!.

$\displaystyle \tan\left(\pm\pi{\rm i}\right) = \pm{\rm i}\tanh\left(\pi\right)$

Why do you believe it's an essential singularity? Just plain residue theorem with a first order pole is all you need to solve this problem.

@FelixMarin $\pm\pi i$ are not contained in $\Gamma$

Why not write $tan z=\dfrac{\sin z}{\cos z}$ and apply resiude theorem.

@AngaeMT Sure, but considering that Res${z=\pi /2} f(z) = \displaystyle\lim{z \to \pi/2} (z- \pi/2)f(z)$, how does one find such a limit when the pole is not in the form of a linear factor? Perhaps write $\cos z = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(z- \pi/2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ and so $\frac{\cos z}{z - \pi/2} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(z- \pi/2)^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$. When $n=0$, we get a (residue) coefficient of $1$?

Notice that
$$
\lim_{z\to\pi/2}\frac{\cos z}{z-\pi/2}=\lim_{z\to\pi/2}\frac{\cos z-\cos(\pi/2)}{z-\pi/2}=\left.\frac{d}{dz}\cos z,\right|_{z=\pi/2}
$$

@NinadMunshi Any help on the work I've provided in the comments?

You have the wrong Taylor series for $\cos z$. About $\frac{\pi}{2}$ it should be odd powers and odd factorials only and should look like the $\sin z$ coefficients about $0$.

@NinadMunshi ah, you're right.  So $\cos z = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(z-\pi/2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

No, $\sin(\pi/2)=1$.

You are forgetting the other terms in the integrand.

First, we rewrite $\tan z$:
$$\int_\Gamma \frac{\tan z}{z^2+\pi^2} \,dz = \int_\Gamma \frac{\sin z}{\cos z (z^2+\pi^2)} \, dz$$
As $\cos z$ has a zero at $z=\pi/2$, we may write
$$\cos z = \left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \frac{\cos z}{\left( z - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$
The circle $\Gamma$ contains the pole $z= \frac{\pi}{2}$ and does not contain the poles $\pm \pi i$. Hence, it suffices to merely find the residue at $ =\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z = \pi/2} f(z) = \lim_{z \to \pi/2} \frac{\sin z}{ \left[\cos z (z^2 + \pi^2)\right]'} =  \dots = - \frac{4}{5 \pi^2}$$
Thus, by the Residue theorem,
$$\int_\Gamma \frac{\tan z}{z^2+\pi^2} \,dz = 2\pi i \left( - \frac{4}{5\pi^2} \right) = -\frac{8i}{5\pi}$$
